# How use fadeIn or similar on v-show

Tags: vue.js

I need to use the fadeIn effect on v-show.
I can fire function when click is fire on item Cadastro, but when v-show fires I don't have control with the behavior.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="app">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="top-menu col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 item-menu">
                    <a @click="showCadastro()">Cadastro</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 item-menu">
                    <a>Imprimir</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" v-show="subMenuCadastro">
                <div class="col-md-3 sub-menu">
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                    <a>Produto</a>
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                    <a>Cliente</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                    <a>Técnico</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    subMenuCadastro: false
  }
})

App.showCadastro = function() {
  this.subMenuCadastro = !this.subMenuCadastro;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transitions: https://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html

Setting a `transition` property on the element where you have a `v-for` will create some classes for you to use on your CSS:

```
<div class="row" v-show="subMenuCadastro" transition="fadeIn">
  ...
</div>
```

Then you can use the following classes on the element: `fadeIn-transition`, `fadeIn-enter`, `fadeIn-leave`. Take a look at the docs for more info.

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/q3c81c5q/

Comment: Thanks, it  works. The transition system is really interesting, I will try with js functions too.